# How do I use an api link instead of a local json file in react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know it's a silly question but I really can't find anything elsewhere.
I want to use this very code to render a table. Just instead of the local file, MOCK_DATA.json, I want to fetch data from an API. What changes do I need to make?

I am very new to react (even programming for that matter), so please don't mind me if the question sounds too obvious.

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import { useTable } from 'react-table'
import MOCK_DATA from './MOCK_DATA.json'
import { COLUMNS } from './columns'
import './table.css'

export const BasicTable = () => {
  const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
  const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, [])

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    footerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  })

  return (
    <>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          {footerGroups.map(footerGroup => (
            <tr {...footerGroup.getFooterGroupProps()}>
              {footerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <td {...column.getFooterProps()}>{column.render('Footer')}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can't you define ```MOCK_DATA```as an empty object, and fetch the data afterward? 
```ferch(api).then(res.json()).then(res=>{MOCK_DATA = res})```

Comment: Using third library app like `AXIOS` or `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use axios, but if your project is new i always recommend to use fetch native browser api:
[FETCH API DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
 const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
```